# How to take a picture using a webcam and have the picture uploaded directed or automatically into my php form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have been trying to build a data capture and biometric (finger print) form where a webcam is attached to the PC and such that when you click on the add/upload image button, the system will automatically launch the webcam and when you take a shot using the webcam, the image is automatically uploaded to the form.

A simple example is the process of applying for a new driving license. The officer will ask you to fill a form and the form data are transferred into the software and then you are asked to stand before a camera for a photo shot. In some cases finger prints of the applicant is also taken and uploaded to the system.

I am developing the web application using Dreamweaver, PHP and MySQL. For now I am only familiar with PHP. No knowledge of Java programming.

Your tips are welcomed and thank you in advance

Mike

Comment: You can't do this in PHP alone. You will need to hire a Java/Flash/etc.. programmer.

Comment: @AzizSaleh I think there's a jquery interface.

Comment: Chrome has a [webcam view feature](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719294/how-can-i-use-chrome-webcam-api-and-the-processing-js-to-manipulate-the-video) that you can use with JavaScript.

Comment: @ Strawberry: How do I go about the JQuery interface please?

Comment: @Strawberry True, however keep in mind the jquery interface still uses something for the backend (Java/Flash/Etc..).

Comment: @PrinceMichael Try Googling "jquery webcam interface" there are plenty of examples you can use.

Comment: @tadman: How do I integrate the Chrome  webcam view feature into the application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kindly try this code for the image capture [from agurchand on TheOnlyTutorials.com](http://theonlytutorials.com/capture-web-camera-image-php-jquery/#comment-25186):

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>WebCam jQuery and PHP script</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
    <style>
        #camera_wrapper, #show_saved_img{float:left; width: 650px;}
    </style>
 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/webcam.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            //give the php file path
            webcam.set_api_url( 'saveimage.php' );
            webcam.set_swf_url( 'scripts/webcam.swf' );
            webcam.set_quality( 100 ); // Image quality (1 - 100)
            webcam.set_shutter_sound( true ); // play shutter click sound
 
            var camera = $('#camera');
            camera.html(webcam.get_html(600, 460));
 
            $('#capture_btn').click(function(){
                //take snap
                webcam.snap();
            });
 
            //after taking snap call show image
            webcam.set_hook( 'onComplete', function(img){
                $('#show_saved_img').html('<img src="' + img + '">');
                //reset camera for next shot
                webcam.reset();
            });
 
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Capture photo with Web Camera - PHP Script</h1>
 
    <!-- camera screen -->
    <div id="camera_wrapper">
    <div id="camera"></div>
    <br />
    <button id="capture_btn">Capture</button>
    </div>
    <!-- show captured image -->
    <div id="show_saved_img" ></div>
</body>
</html>


Saveimage.php

<?php
 
//set random name for the image, used time() for uniqueness
 
$filename =  time() . '.jpg';
$filepath = 'saved_images/';
 
//read the raw POST data and save the file with file_put_contents()
$result = file_put_contents( $filepath.$filename, file_get_contents('php://input') );
if (!$result) {
    print "ERROR: Failed to write data to $filename, check permissionsn";
    exit();
}
 



echo $filepath.$filename;
?>
```

See [the source](http://theonlytutorials.com/capture-web-camera-image-php-jquery/#comment-25186) for the PHP portion.

Also download the webcam.js library from https://code.google.com/p/jpegcam/

Comment: source http://theonlytutorials.com/capture-web-camera-image-php-jquery/#comment-25186

Comment: @Shog9: Thank you so much. I will try it out